# How to redefine uint_least8_t for unit tests

Tags: c, gcc, typedef

I am trying to unit test code on x86 that uses uint_least8_t. On one of the targets this is actually a uint16_t so I'd like to be able to unit test with uint_least8_t being both uint8_t and uint16_t. What's a good way of redefining uint_least8_t (and variants) to 16-bit types?

I tried to do a simple `typedef uint16_t uint_least8_t;` but the compiler complains about the redefinition. I could replace all uint_least8_t with yet another type (ie. `my_uint_least8_t`), but would prefer not to have to modify all the code. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

(C11, GCC)

Comment: If you're not too squeamish about UB, maybe `#define uint_least8_t uint16_t`?

Comment: Don't love it, but certainly an option

Comment: Using `#define` is probably the correct answer because it is local to the current translation unit and "mocks" the `uint_least8_t` type, quite unintrusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `stdint.h` file in some test dir. Add the path to that to compiler include path with `-I` for *the whole project*.

In that `stdint.h` do `#include_next <stdint.h>`. After that in that `stdint.h` `#undef` all preprocessor macros when needed and `#define uint_least8_t uint16_t`.

Comment: How will `#undef` help? These are likely typedefs.

Comment: `__{U,}INT_LEAST8_{MAX,MIN}__` and `{U,}INT_LEAST8_{MAX,MIN,WIDTH}` has to be undef.

Comment: These macros should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: They only need to be undef + redefined if they are actually used by the code base though.

Comment: This seems to be working well so far. Basically, I have `my_std_int.h` which includes `stdint.h`, and then `#undef`s `INT8_MIN, INT8_MAX, and UINT8_MAX` and then creates preprocessor macros for all the types I care about (ie. `#define uint8_t uint16_t`)

Answer (score 2):

If there is only 1 file, then simple `#define uint_least8_t uint8_t` after including `stdint.h` should be enough.

I've tested it with code below and it seemed to work

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define uint_least8_t uint8_t

int main() {
    /* Rest of the code ... */
    printf("uint_least8_t size: %zu\n", sizeof(uint_least8_t)); /* This printf is an example */
}
```

Comment: There are dozens of c sources and the corresponding cpp tests in the google test framework and remembering to tag each one is somewhat cumbersome and error prone. It's what I've been doing to test things but am looking for a better long term solution. Also, these do still need to be compiled for targets that support 8bit types so switching back and forth would be needed.

Comment: This works fairly well in combination with @KamilCuk's answer. I use the intermediate header file to replace `<stdint.h>` in all my files, and then can use some macro to switch all types between 8 vs 16 bit globally